# Ios Provisioning profile is expiring

Tags: ios, xcode5, ipa, ios-provisioning

I have create an new application in Xcode.
But it shows a warning as below

*Target Integrity
Provisioning profile is expiring*: **olpApplicationid**

In this warning shows old application id but i have generate a new provision profile certificate. and its not allowed to make an IPA. 
please some one help me to resolve this.

Comment: This is usually an error in the provisioning profile on the developer website. Check there. If you have to, recreate it.

Comment: Thanks @ErikBean I have recreated but after that also same error occurred.

Comment: Is your iOS developer certificate expiring soon? I know when I was coming up for renewal I had similar issues.

Comment: No, just a month ago i renewed my Developer Account.Now i revoke all my account and create a fresh one. but still it's shown warning.

Comment: Try a profile refresh. Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> <team account in question> -> View Details

Comment: sorry @ErikBean i forgot to tell u this and i have already Refresh here from suggested by stackOverflow.

Comment: I am too try this before, but i can't resolve. i have try to resolve over a day.

Comment: Refresh again now that you messed with the provisioning on the dev portal. It's tricky, the connection between the dev portal, Xcode, and keychain is a b**** and a nightmare. It needs to be 100% redone in my option.

Comment: Hi @ErikBean, thank u so much for ur guidance, i was revoke all userid also refresh account in Xcode finally delete all invalid certificates from Apple Developer site. Now warning Went Out.

Comment: I'm rewriting it as an answer. Mark that as correct so your question can have resolution. Glad I can solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in comment:

Revoking and cleaning out your provisioning provoke on the developer portal followed up by a refresh in Xcode solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that comment above!!  I always forget where this is, and you helped me find it. +2 to you.  "Try a profile refresh. Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> <team account in question> -> View Details"

Comment: NOTE: You may have to quit/launch Xcode for the warning to go away after deleting or updating the offending profile.